# accessing another subnet behind proxy

Tags: routing, squid

I have squid proxy with dansguardian with ip x.x.1.125 and all computer have this ip as their gateway. Now I need them to access an application on x.x.othernetwork.41 ip. But when I turn on ip forwarding, they can access this ip but the internet becomes open even without proxy settings in the browser. In other words, the users get full access internet when I enable forwarding.

I want them to access this application on another subnet but also access internet through proxy only.The proxy can ping the software ip x.x.othernetwork.41.

x.x.1.125 has single network card.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of achieving this.

- You may add firewall rules using `iptables` in the proxy server that will block outgoing connection to port 80/443 for local LAN, so that the users won't be able to use internet without using the proxy.
- Disable IP forwarding in the proxy server and configure proper route to the other network using `route` command so that the packet are routed to the right gateway to reach the other network.

The problem is in your setup, you are using the proxy server as gateway, which is actually not a router, as you have said, it has only one ethernet interface. So you should consider configuring your LAN so, that the computers are configured with the correct/actual gateway address. This way they will be able to reach other networks without going through the proxy server. A proxy server doesn't need to be the default gateway to work properly.

Comment: if i disbale the forwarding the users behind the proxy cannot ping the app server on the other subnet.
even without forwarding, the proxy server can ping the app server b/c its gateway is the firewall.
i add this command but still not pinging.
route add -net x.x.x.othersubnet netmask 255.255.255.0 gw x.x.x.gatewayonrouter dev eth0

please help.

Comment: without ip forwarding the packet won't be passed through the proxy server. that's why it's not working. So you will need to have the route at client pc. I have updated my answer. As I have said, you should consider changing your configuration or put a firewall rule at the proxyserver to prevent forwarding to port 80: something like `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s x.x.1.125/24  -d !x.x.othernetwork.41 -j REJECT`